# Create Azure VM in multiple regions

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I have a Azure VM in one region which is in East US. To improve performance I want to have this VM serve multiple regions(Ex: WestEurope, SouthEastAsia, West US) as well. Do I need to create fresh VMs in all regions? Or there is any better way to do this using a single VM which will server multiple regions?

Comment: are you using traffic manager?

Answer (score 0):

Technically Azure Front Door might work for you if you are serving http requests from the vm (it has caching). but in a general sense - you need to deploy the vm to every region. You can use scripts\arm templates to streamline this process